# how to update the order total in checkout page?

Tags: commerce

I'm calculating discount amount base on total order amount. how can I show the discount amount like something what coupon module has done? (see the picture)

[image]

what is the correct way to update the total order amount? I mean how should I subtract the discount amount from the order total so if any products has been removed or added it always works correctly??

Comment: do u still need solution for your problem or found answer?

Comment: yes my problem is solved, I used the first answer which has been suggested by @Molot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7).

First, for integrity purposes, write a [validator](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#validate) that will ensure all amounts are correct, and if not - update them & show form to user again.

Second - use [AJAX](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax). Drupal allows only for one callback, so your new one will have to take care of calling the original one in the first place, and you may have some problems if you will [need to replace more than one form element](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8529/is-it-possible-to-replace-more-than-one-form-element-wrappers-triggered-by-onl), but it can be done.

Comment: tanx for the solution Molot, I didn't need to update more than one element and everythings works fine

Comment: I'm glad it worked. If I could humbly ask you to mark my answer as accepted, so other will see there is working solution?