# Multiple Field , same ajax callback

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I created a custom field. The hook_field_widget_form has an submit element with an ajax callback:

```
  //Add more
  $element['add_zone'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#name' => $field_name . '-add_more-' .'name',
    '#value' => t('+'),
    '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
    '#submit' => array('dms_polygone_add_more_add_one'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'dms_polygone_add_more_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'zones-fieldset-wrapper-'. $field_name,
    ),
  );
```

I add 2 fields of my custom field type to a node. Ex: field_polygone (field type: polygone) and field_polygone_2 (field type: polygone). 
When i press the 'add_more' button of my first field_polygone, my callback function 'dms_polygone_add_more_add_one' thinks the trigger element is field_polygone_2.

Callback function:

```
function dms_polygone_add_more_callback($form, $form_state) {
  //@todo: $i gebruiken voor veld als er meerdere waardes zijn toegestaan.
  $parents = $form_state['triggering_element']['#parents'];
  return $form[$parents[0]][$parents[1]][$parents[2]]['zones'];
}
```

$parents[0] is the field_name => When i press 'add_more' , the $parents[0] variable in the callback function should be 'field_polygone', but its field 'field_polygone_2'.

How can is solve this problem? Why does the callback function think the trigger element is field_polygone_2 instead of field_polygone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue in Drupal 8. I had one form with multiple entities (not drupal entities) that had an identical subset of fields and each had their own button. My `$form_state->getTriggeringElement()` would always show the last of these buttons, no matter which I clicked. My issue was that I was not setting `#name` on the buttons and they were both defaulting to `op` (they had the same `#name` value). Explicitly setting a unique `#name` for each button resolved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

The following link helped me to change 2 elements from a form through AJAX callback, whitout having to return the whole `$form` :

[Is it possible to replace more than one form element (wrappers) triggered by only one #ajax trigger element?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8529/is-it-possible-to-replace-more-than-one-form-element-wrappers-triggered-by-onl)

Comment: This is not the answer of question.