# Stack ajax_command_replace commands?

Tags: ajax

I am wondering if it is possible to stack two `ajax_command_replace` commands. In other words, to have code that looks like this:

```
<br>
$commands = array();<br>
$commands[] = ajax_command_replace($selector1, $data1);<br>
$commands[] = ajax_command_replace($selector2, $data2);<br>
ajax_deliver(array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);<br>
```

and then to expect both commands to run?

When I try this, the first command runs just fine, but the second command does not. I have reversed the order of the two commands, and sure enough, the (new) first command now runs, but the (new) second command does not. I have also looked at the page after the `ajax_deliver` has run, and the first command did not destroy the html on the page, so the second command's selector is still there. I have also added a dummy `ajax_command_alert` just to be sure that I can run multiple commands, and that works as well.
An added comment:  If you use ajax_command_replace, you lose the tags on the selector you have chosen.  Two options to get around this are (1) Use ajax_command_html (which retains the outer tag) or (2) include the outer tag information in the html for the ajax_command_replace.**I still, however, cannot stack two ajax_command_replace or ajax_command_html commands.**

Comment: Maybe this could help, https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8529/is-it-possible-to-replace-more-than-one-form-element-wrappers-triggered-by-onl

Comment: Thank you for this idea, but I had already tried it, and it does not solve my problem.