# form ajax how to change multiple elements

Tags: forms, ajax

How can i change multiple form elements in ajax callback and get this changes in future ajax callbacks?

i would like to set custom class to multiple fieldset's in ajax callback function:

```
   if (something){
    $form['fieldset_01']['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('custom_class'));
    $form['fieldset_02']['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('custom_class'));
    }else if (somethingelse)
    $form['fieldset_11']['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('custom_class'));
    $form['fieldset_12']['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('custom_class'));
} etc...
return $form;
```

When $form is returned, the element that i have set in this call in rendered fine, with new class but the element's that i have rendered in previous calls have lost this new class. Like they were rendered with default values.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Already asked, and good answer: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7243/can-i-use-ajax-to-target-multiple-form-elements-from-one-input

Comment: I am not sure if this answers my question .. In my case, i return $form and every element is showing ok, but in the next callback everything is back to original. That is the problem ..

Comment: so ask a new question and make it clear. Little hint - callback is only to tell Drupal what to update. Permanent changes are to be made in main form creation function, even for ajax calls!