# Changing 2 Elements on Ajax Callback

Tags: 8, entities, forms, ajax

I have an element `$form['elements']['manufacturer']`. On change, I want to change `$form['elements']['form_factor']` and `$form['elements']['model']`.

Currently I have:

```
$form['elements']['manufacturer']['#ajax'] = [
    'callback' => 'formChanged',
    'wrapper' => 'form-factor',
    'event' => 'change',
];
```

which works and changes the form-factor. But, **I want to change the model** as well.

Iniside `formChanged` return form-factor in the callback function, so I can't return model element.

```
function formChanged(array &$form, FormStateInterface $formState){
  $form["elements"]["form_factor"]["#value"] = 0;
  return $form["elements"]["form_factor"];
}
```

[Reading from past posts](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7243/can-i-use-ajax-to-target-multiple-form-elements-from-one-input#answer-84593), one option was to return the whole form inside `formChanged` (`return $form`), but this doesn't seem like a good approach.

I can't do something like, having 2 callbacks:

```
$form['elements']['manufacturer']['#ajax'] = [
   [
    'callback' => 'formChanged',
    'wrapper' => 'form-factor',
    'event' => 'change',
   ],
   [
    'callback' => 'anothercallback',
    'wrapper' => 'another-one',
    'event' => 'change',
   ]
];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the wrapper key

```
$form['elements']['manufacturer']['#ajax'] = [
  'callback' => 'formChanged',
  'event' => 'change',
];
```

Your callback

```
public function formChanged(array &$form, FormStateInterface $formState){
    $form['elements']['form_factor']['#value'] = 0;
    $form['elements']['model']['#value'] = 0;
    $response = new \Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse();
    $response->addCommand(new \Drupal\Core\Ajax\ReplaceCommand(".form-item-form-factor", $form['elements']['form_factor']));
    $response->addCommand(new \Drupal\Core\Ajax\ReplaceCommand(".form-item-model", $form['elements']['model']));
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: works like a charm! thank you

Comment: I didn't have that 'elements' array (maybe it's D9 change) but I had structure like:
$form['field_name']['widget']['#value'] = 0;

Answer (score 3):

Instead of returning a single render array (of all or part of your form) from your `callback`, you will need to return an `AjaxResponse` that contains a  `ReplaceCommand` for each piece of the form you want to replace:

For example, in your callback:

```
$response = new AjaxResponse();
$response
  ->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#edit-form-factor', $form_factor_element))
  ->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#edit-model', $model_element));
return $response;
```

See the guide:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/ajax-api/basic-concepts#sub_form

And the Ajax commands reference:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/ajax-api/core-ajax-callback-commands

Comment: Actually the 2nd param of ReplaceCommand [does accept render arrays](https://i.imgur.com/7dwSgCH.png)

Comment: Thanks for fixing that - I should've read more closely.

Comment: @BradTreloar Thanks for the links! It not only works, but I understand it now.